# I want to install php 5.3.9 in ubuntu 12.04 via apt-get - what repository should I add?

Tags: ubuntu, php5, php-fpm, php53, ubuntu-12.04

I want to install php 5.3.9 in ubuntu 12.04 via apt-get.

> apt-cache show php5-fpm

only lists ***5.3.10-1ubuntu3.1*** and ***5.3.10-1ubuntu3***. There is a critical bug in 5.3.10 ( https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61045&edit=1 ) that I am trying to avoid.

Is there a repository that will let me install php 5.3.9 in ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can use php 5.3.13 from [dotdeb](http://www.dotdeb.org/) repository:

```
sudo echo "deb http://php53.dotdeb.org stable all" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```